Trying pybind11 in window: undefined reference to __imp_PyGILState_Check
I'm trying to get pybind11 to work in windows. I've installed pybind11 using conda-forge, then do the simplest code:
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

compile it with :
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -mavx -IC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pybind11/include -IC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/include/pybind11_global/ -IC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/include/ - pb_test.cpp -o pb_test

The -I path avoids earlier problem of Python.h not found. But now, I get the bunch of errors related to undefined reference to '_imp_Py*' type of errors. Too many to count. My guess is that I am missing a linker, after some searching, the suggested hint seems to involved the /anaconda3/libs folder with all the dll. If I tried that -lc:/Users/beng/anaconda3/libs/python311 or python3, none of it works. It will instead complain:
cannot find -lC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/libs/python311
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But both python3.dll and python311.dll are in that folder.
I've checked post like but nothing that helps me so far:
Pybind11 error undefined reference to `Py_GetVersion'
Please help. I'm seriously stuck. Not sure my suspicion about linking error is even correct.

Are your path formats correct?  I'm used to references to the C drive being in a form like  /c/ instead of C:\  or C:/ in unixy/linuxy Windows shells.

I finally got it to work
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -mavx -shared -IC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pybind11/include -IC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/include/ -LC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/libs/ pb_test.cpp -lpython311 -o pb_test.cp311-win_amd64.pyd

I have to give it -L to tell it the folder and then -lpython311 to make it link correctly. I think the location of the -l is important too. Lastly the output extension is also important for python code to be able to use the library later on. Not sure the -shared is important but didn't removed it and retry.
In case, you have multiple cpp files (when it grows beyond simple example), you have to put all your cpp files and output filename is best to match the name of your new python library
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -mavx -shared -IFOLDER1 -IFOLDER2 -LFOLDER4LINKER wrapper.cpp binding.cpp complicated_algorithm.cpp -lpython311 -o library_name.cp311-win_amd64.pyd

Also: doing this in a Powershell Prompt helps to know the folders needed to include
> python -m pybind11 --includes
-IC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/include/ -IC:/Users/beng_/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pybind11/include 

As for the proper extension to use: If you do this in python interpreter
import distutils
print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX'))  # .cp311-win_amd64.pyd

It's probably simple and obvious for people who know how to set compiler flags but I was a noob to such things. It's a good learning experience for me and I hope to leave this answer here so that another noob can converge to the answer faster and save time.
